# Error creating database table using FirebirdSQL

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to add tables to a FirebirdSQL database using FlameRobin but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( CREATE TABLE drinks
(
    ...
) )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -104
can't format message 13:896 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 3, column 5
.
```

I've tried googling the problem but have been unable to find a solution. Does anyone know what the issue is here?

Comment: It is a syntax error, show the actual `CREATE TABLE` statement you are using. Your statement has a dot (`.`) where none is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands it looks like the `CREATE TABLE` in the question is the actual statement. In that case you are getting the error because it is simply invalid syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE drinks (
    ...
)
```

If I execute this in Flamerobin, I get almost the same error (except for me at line 2, column 5 (the first `.`), as the parser expects a column name there. At the `...` you need to specify the actual columns (and optionally constraints) of the table.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE drinks (
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```